# Jumpy animation bootstrap accordion without any margin-top

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here's my code.

`Spanish` should open `Class 1`, `Class 2`, and `Class 1` should open `Samsung`. `Class 2` should open `Microsoft`.

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion"><div class="panel" style="margin-left: -15px;height: 130px">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="vgroupholder panel-title collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href=".titleSpanish" onclick="removevBgs();" style="background-color: transparent;" aria-expanded="false">

                        <div class="groupicon">
                            <div class="groupicontext">S</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grouptext">
                            <div class="grouptitle">Spanish</div>
                        </div>


                    </div>      
                </div></div><div class="panel-collapse titleSpanish collapse in" aria-expanded="false" style="">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                            <div class="vgroupholder panel-body" data-parent="#titleSpanish" data-toggle="collapse" href="#titleSpanish-Class1" style="background-color: transparent;" aria-expanded="true">

                                <div class="groupicon" style="width: 80px;height: 80px;margin-left: 20px;">
                                    <div class="groupicontext" style="font-size: 40px;">C1</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="grouptext">
                                    <div class="grouptitle">Class 1</div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="titleSpanish-Class1" aria-expanded="true" style="">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="vsubgroupholder panel-body" data-toggle="collapse">

                                        <div onclick="require(" shell").openexternal("https:="" www.samsung.com="" ")"="" class="groupicon" onmouseover="joinHover(this);" onmouseout="joinunHover(this);" style="width: 80px;height: 40px;margin-left: 20px;border-radius: 10px;background-color: #E1F6FA;">
                                            <div class="groupicontext" style="font-size: 25px;margin-top: 13px;">Join</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="grouptext">
                                            <div class="grouptitle" onclick="openExternal();">Samsung</div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                        </div></div></div></div><div class="panel-collapse titleSpanish collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style="">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                            <div class="vgroupholder panel-body" data-parent="#titleSpanish" data-toggle="collapse" href="#titleSpanish-Class2" style="background-color: transparent;">

                                <div class="groupicon" style="width: 80px;height: 80px;margin-left: 20px;">
                                    <div class="groupicontext" style="font-size: 40px;">C2</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="grouptext">
                                    <div class="grouptitle">Class 2</div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="titleSpanish-Class2">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="vsubgroupholder panel-body" data-toggle="collapse">

                                        <div onclick="require(" shell").openexternal("https:="" www.microsoft.com="" ")"="" class="groupicon" onmouseover="joinHover(this);" onmouseout="joinunHover(this);" style="width: 80px;height: 40px;margin-left: 20px;border-radius: 10px;background-color: #E1F6FA;">
                                            <div class="groupicontext" style="font-size: 25px;margin-top: 13px;">Join</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="grouptext">
                                            <div class="grouptitle" onclick="openExternal();">Microsoft</div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                        </div></div></div></div></div>
```

---

As you can see, I have 2 accordions inside one. This works. However, when opening `Samsung` or `Microsoft`. (2nd accordion), it has a jumpy animation. Does anybody know why?

There are no further relevant files.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not getting any jumpiness on core bootstrap install, or you mean something else with jumpiness?: https://i.gyazo.com/bfa7beb5feba9e9bd24dcb4bed12ea5f.gif

Comment: huh - i see that. For me, the expanding into the 'join' part is jumpy.

Comment: @GhostPengy its more of a smooth animation actually, but when it finished, it jumps a little.

Comment: Sounds like performance issue then. It can be from using additional libraries to the hardware itself.

Comment: It is a bad clipping of a loop of a gif. That jump is just gif looping over, not actual script.
Few things you can try:   
1. Run it in incognito mode, if it runs smooth, it is browser extensions / settings messing with you.   
2. Remove all external libraries, and only leave Bootstrap core, if it does not lag, it is a library.   
3. Try another device, if it does not lag on it, it can be the device at fault, meaning it does not have enough juice to run it smoothly. It often is issue on mobile devices.
   
You should see a change in at least one of these steps.

Comment: @GhostPengy I'm running an electron app, I don't know if this is of any help?

Comment: I will not be any help there sadly. Not familiar with it at all.